# Rendering HTML without an activity

Tags: android, html, webview

I'd like to render some HTML for the side effects of such rendering (i.e. pinging a backend server). When my activity is visible, of course I can just show the HTML in a WebView. However, when the activity is not visible, I want to render the HTML without showing the activity as this would be disruptive to the user.

Is this possible to do on Android?

Comment: I dodn't understand what you mean by 'rendering HTML'. Do you mean you want to perform some sort of HTTP-based action behind the scenes?

Comment: I guess I mean I want it rendered/parsed/run offscreen, without the need for an activity to be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the classes/interfaces in [org.apache.http](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html) for ways of handling HTTP actions without using a WebView.

You could place your code in an Android Service which will run without interrupting the user.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing I forgot to mention, I have the HTML locally, it's not served up remotely. Yes, I have a good place (in a service) to actually do the work.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how this would work. I've looked at the org.apache.hhtp classes and can't see how they would help me to render the local html I have. Any more detailed pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @dhaag23: OK, what confused me was that you mentioned 'pinging a backend server' so I assumed you wanted to silently access an HTTP service somewhere which is why I mentioned that package. I'm still confused that 'rendering' usually means displaying in a visual sense which isn't possible without a UI view such as an Activity will provide. If you simply want to parse html then try something like JSoup or even treat it like XML and use the various Android XML libraries.

Comment: Sure, while rendering usually means displaying in a visual sense, you can still parse the HTML, run the JavaScript etc without showing anything. I'm giving you the +1 for all the great suggestions as well as the check. I think I now have the simplest solution: just instantiate a WebView using the service's context.